# Auto increment jumps by more than the number of rows inserted?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am facing a problem while inserting data in a mysql table. Auto increment jumps by more than the number of rows inserted. Follow below steps to reproduce the problem. This table is not referencing with another table. No trigger is created on this table. No delete query is executed on table.

Step 1 - Create a table in mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_hostel_rooms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_sharing_for_room` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Step 2 - Insert 10 rows into table and analyze the result. This will insert 10 rows and AUTO_INCREMENT value will be set to 11. This is also expected.

```
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '101', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '102', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '103', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '104', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '105', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '106', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '107', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '108', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '109', '3');
INSERT INTO `new_db`.`tbl_hostel_rooms` (`id`, `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '110', '3');
```

Step 3 - Insert 10 more rows using this query, and analyze the result.

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_hostel_rooms`(`hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room`) select `hostel_id`, `room_no`, `total_sharing_for_room` from tbl_hostel_rooms;
```

**This will insert 10 more rows and AUTO_INCREMENT value will be set to 26. This is not expected. Now you insert a single row only, the AUTO_INCREMENT column id will be started from 27.**

What is the solution to this problem.

Comment: An autoincrement value is there to identify a row but not for numbering rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to, explicitly mention the "id" column which is auto increment field. Try to remove this field from the query. May be issue  will resolved.